React Native New Architecture - CodePush does not register for frame updates
I'm running RN 0.76.3 with New Architecture enabled, and react-native-code-push 9.0.0
When downloading a CodePush update, I don't get progress events before the download has finished.
I've found that the reason is that the method
- (void)didUpdateFrame:(RCTFrameUpdate *)update
of the CodePush module is never invoked, because
- (void)registerModuleForFrameUpdates:(id<RCTBridgeModule>)module withModuleData:(RCTModuleData *)moduleData;
is never called with the CodePush module.
I can see that RCTTurboModuleManager.mm contains this code which should register CodePush for updates, but because bridge is nil, it doesn't happen.
  if (_bridge) {
    RCTModuleData *data = [[RCTModuleData alloc] initWithModuleInstance:(id<RCTBridgeModule>)module
                                                                 bridge:_bridge
                                                         moduleRegistry:_bridge.moduleRegistry
                                                viewRegistry_DEPRECATED:nil
                                                          bundleManager:nil
                                                      callableJSModules:nil];
    [_bridge registerModuleForFrameUpdates:(id<RCTBridgeModule>)module withModuleData:data];
  }

I guess there's some method or protocol that needs to be implemented in CodePush.m to make it register for frame updates with the New Architecture?

To answer your question first:
At least one things that is missing is event emitting capabilities, but I doubt that alone will fix your problems.
The react-native-code-push library depends on code-push, which basically contains the JS code. But in order to support the new arch, the whole project needs to be a Turbo Module. So it needs the JSI interface and codegen information.

I also use Codepush and decided to take another approach, since the existing Codepush library contains a lot of legacy code (Windows for example). After doing some research I figured it was likely less work to start from scratch and only implement the things needed for my project. On a high level you only need to have this functionality:
Build time

Create new bundles for Android and iOS (simply the existing react-native CLI commands)
Upload to cloud storage

Run time

A way to check the currently active bundle and compare it to the cloud bundles ( = version check)
Download new bundles when available and write to the file system
Point RN to most recent bundle
cleanup of old bundles

Edit
Some key parts of the interface, adding logic is going to lead to to a lot of code here ...
// TS Spec file
import { TurboModule, TurboModuleRegistry } from "react-native";

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  getAppVersion(): Promise<string>;
  initiateUpdate(): Promise<{ success: boolean }>;
  checkForUpdate(): Promise<{ updateAvailable: boolean }>;
  restartApp(): void;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing<Spec>('OTA');

Then I basically have 3 main files containing most of the logic:
Codepush.mm
Contains the C++ interface for the spec file + 4 core functions:
@interface OTA: NSObject <NativeOTASpec>

- (void)downloadPackage:(NSString *)updatePackageUrl destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject;
- (void)unzipFileAtPath:(NSString *)zipPath toDestination:(NSString *)destinationPath completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
- (void)removeFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL;
+ (nullable NSURL *)bundleURL;

@end

DownloadManager.mm
Has one main function, rest is monitoring and safety checks. It downloads the zip folder from the request url, unzips it, and provides a progress callback during download. On download success the file is verified and if all checks succeed the app is rebooted and the new Bundle will replace the existing one
- (id)init:(NSString *)downloadFilePath
operationQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)operationQueue
progressCallback:(void (^)(float))progressCallback
doneCallback:(void (^)(BOOL))doneCallback
failCallback:(void (^)(NSError *err))failCallback;

FolderUtils.mm
Manages creation and deletion of folders for the different bundles, plus cleanup of deprecated bundle version
Pseudo code

Thanks for your response. Can you share some code?

Can you be a bit more specific in what you need, adding everything here is going to be a lot of work. It involves JS code, native iOS code, native Android code and my backend code.

Another question:
You say "The react-native-code-push library depends on code-push, which basically contains the JS code. But in order to support the new arch, the whole project needs to be a Turbo Module. So it needs the JSI interface and codegen information."
My impression was that NA had a compatibility layer that would handle stuff like this?
Also, I find it hard to see any documentation about the methods used for RN Code Push and other modules, the only results I get by googling is the source code itself?

Not sure what NA stands for ... I'll update my question with some key parts of my logic

NA = New Architecture
